# Amazon SNS - Get information about number of successful and failed notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send notifications using Amazon SNS by subscribing endpoints to a SNS topic. I have configured events to send email when notifications fail. But is there a way to know how many notifications were successful and how many of them failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is, you have to use [CloudWatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/sns-metricscollected.html); specifically `NumberOfNotificationsDelivered` and `NumberOfNotificationsFailed`. [image: AWS CloudWatch Metrics Example]

The above is a quick screenshot of what a graph configured with those metrics might look like.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not tell how many endpoints were successful and how many failed